# In VLSI Testing why do we perform mbist before scan insertion in DFT (Design for testability)?

Tags: vlsi

In DFt (Design for testability), we can perform MBIST at any stage of DFT Flow. What is the specific advantage of doing Mbist Before scan insertion?

Answer (score 0):

Some times we have to store the test vectors in SRAM's for testing convenience.
So we do MBIST and ensure that our memory is working fine to store the test vectors and then we do scan insertion using the stored Test-Vectors..

Hope I answered your question ..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about dft insertion phase, not test execution phase.

Performing scan insertion after mbist can make the circuit inserted by mbist testable, thus increase test coverage.